# Diablo 3 adding commands

Tags: wine

Okey so I got the battle.net launcher to work and even Diablo 3 to launch. But it just hangs around on the retrieving hero list. And [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=29952) tells me that I am supposed to add  the

> setarch i386 -L -B -R -3" and "-launch

however, I have no idea how I should do just that (Just installed Ubuntu)

Comment: So how do you launch it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the launcher installed myself but i would look for game specific options to add these options to the launcher. If that doesn't work, i would check if the launcher can make a desktop link for diablo3 and then the options could be added to the command line. You could also explore "PlayOnLinux". I haven't had a good track record with it but i hear great things about it for people with little experience with linux like you or me. PlayOnLinux can be downloaded through Ubuntu's "software center".

Hope it helps.